# How to embed a subfigure inside another subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, subcaption

I have multiple plots which I built using Tikz. I need to put all of them in the next configuration. Can anyone give me an idea of how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Do you want captions there? If not, you can use `tabular` with 2 rows and 2 columns and insert image in each cell.

Comment: I added more information. Important, each plot was done using Tikz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? (adjustment on figures widths are needed)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\subfloat[faa]{\label{fig.a}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfill
\subfloat[fbb]{\label{fig.b}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}} \\
%%
\subfloat[fcc]{\label{fig.c}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
\hfill
\subfloat[fdd]{\label{fig.d}
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\[-3pt]
\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{global}\label{fig.global}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can the \includegraphics be replaced by the Tikz code?

Comment: Yes, but I recommend you to create separated pdf for each TikZ figure, using the `standalone` class. So you don't need to compile such code every time. It make your document process faster, and make the code clearer.

Comment: In your solution, you are setting up the size using width=0.45, however, that is part of the \includegraphics options. How can you setting up the size using the plot code? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JohnFontecha, one more reason to create separated images.

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate that there are multiple ways to do things.  Note that every `subfigure` is a glorified `minipage`, and every image (box) is treated just like a single letter in a line of text.  (`\subfloat` puts the contents into a `savebox`, then put both the `savebox` and the caption into a `minipage`.)

Also, minipages change the values of `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` inside the environment.  BTW, `\lineskip` is the minimum vertical separation between the bottom of one line and the top of the next (as opposed to `\baselineskip`, which is the minimum separation between baselines).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{faa}\label{fig.a}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}% glorified minipage
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{fbb}\label{fig.b}
\end{subfigure}%
\\
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}% glorified minipage
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{fcc}\label{fig.c}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}% glorified minipage
\lineskip=0pt
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{fdd}\label{fig.d}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{global}\label{fig.global}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]